# FQL query list of friends that allows apps to access their photos

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am using the iOS Facebook SDK for my application. My app needs to access to user's friends photos.
However some users denies apps to access their photos. What I would like to do is to filter those friends that do not allow apps to access their photos.
My current approach is to get all the friends save the uid in an array, and after that remove those one that are sharing 0 photos. The problem of this approach is that is very inefficient and slow.

Do you know if is there any way to query using FQL or the Graph API about this particular user's friends permission?

The following is my current (very slow) approach.

```
- (void)retrieveFacebookFriends
{
    if (FBSession.activeSession.isOpen)
    {
        FBRequestConnection *fbConnection = [[FBRequestConnection alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray *arrayOfFriendIDS = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        NSMutableArray *arrayOfFriendsNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        [fbConnection addRequest:[FBRequest requestForMyFriends] completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {

            if (!error)
            {
                FBGraphObject *graphObject = (FBGraphObject *)result;

                id content = [graphObject objectForKey:@"data"];

                if ([content count] > 0)
                {
                    //sort the friends by name
                    NSSortDescriptor *descriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"first_name"  ascending:YES];
                    [content sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:descriptor,nil]];

                    id value;
                    for (value in content)
                    {
                        [arrayOfFriendIDS addObject:[value objectForKey:@"id"]];
                        [arrayOfFriendsNames addObject:[value objectForKey:@"name"]];
                    }

                    NSInteger size = [arrayOfFriendIDS count];
                    NSMutableArray *data = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:size];
                    for (NSInteger i = 0; i < size; i++)
                    {
                        FriendRecord *record = [[FriendRecord alloc] init];
                        record.friendID = [arrayOfFriendIDS objectAtIndex:i];
                        record.name = [arrayOfFriendsNames objectAtIndex:i];
                        [data addObject:record];
                    }
                    self.friendRecords = [NSArray arrayWithArray:data];

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                    });

                    __block NSMutableArray *tmpArray = [self.friendRecords mutableCopy];
                    __block int counter = 0;
                    for (value in content)
                    {
                        FBRequest *fql = [FBRequest requestForGraphPath:@"fql"];
                        [fql.parameters setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"SELECT object_id FROM photo WHERE aid IN (SELECT aid FROM album WHERE owner=%@)",[value objectForKey:@"id"]]
                                           forKey:@"q"];

                        [fql startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection *connection,
                                                          id result,
                                                          NSError *error) 
                        {
                            counter++;

                            if (!error)
                            {
                                id permissionData = [result objectForKey:@"data"];                                
                                if ([permissionData count] == 0)
                                {
                                    FriendRecord *record = [[FriendRecord alloc] init];
                                    record.friendID = [value objectForKey:@"id"];
                                    record.name = [value objectForKey:@"id"];
                                    [tmpArray removeObject:record];
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                NSLog(@"error %@", error);
                            }
                            //check if it is the last record
                            if (counter == [self.friendRecords count])
                            {
                                self.friendRecords = [NSArray arrayWithArray:tmpArray];

                                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                                    NSLog(@"filtering is finished");
                                    [self.tableView reloadData];
                                });
                            }
                        }];  
                    }
                }
            }
        }];
        [fbConnection start];
    }
    else
    {
        //open a facebook session
    }
}
```

Ok, I partially solved the problem using this FQL query which is very fast!

```
select uid, name from user where uid in (select owner from album where owner in (select uid2 from friend where uid1 = me())) order by name
```

However some of the friends that are sharing photos with apps are not included in the answer of this query! At first I thought it was because they had no personal albums but then, after verifying that it was not the case, I have no idea why.

Can you please help me to solve this strange problem?
Thank you very much!